# How to horizontally scroll an inner div with text wrapping

Tags: css, html, scroll

I am trying to get a series of inner divs to scroll horizontally inside a fixed width outer div.  I have it working but the only problem is the text in the inner div does not wrap and overflows the next div, because of the white-space:nowrap in the outer div, which accomplishes the scroll. How can I fix this so the inner divs continue to scroll rightward, but the text fits into the inner divs (red boxes)?  Please have a look at this JSFiddle for the code:

[Demo in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6JL3/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentHolder">
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="post">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#515151;
    width:600px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding-top:20px; 
}   

#contentHolder {
    color:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow:auto; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}


.post {
    width:60px;
    height:300px;
    margin:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;

    background-color:#700;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `white-space: normal;` to `.post`